# Scaling stats of 2 footballers to compare them fairly

Tags: statistics

I am trying to compare the statistics of football players from different leagues in a fair manner so that I can evaluate their performance objectively.

For example, player X is a defender that plays in the English Premier League, which for the purpose of this question, we assume is the highest level league in the world. He has a defensive duels win rate of 65% (i.e. he wins 65% of his defensive duels) during the season.

Player Y is also a defender, he plays in the Malaysian football league. His defensive duels win rate is higher at 75%. As the Malaysian football league is a lower level and less competitive league than the English Premier League, it is not fair to compare Player X vs Player Y and say that Player Y is a better defender simply because he has a higher win rate.

To measure the level of the league, I have found some metrics available online. For example, in Football Manager, the English Premier league is rated 4.5 stars and it has a reputation score of 184.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcS5D.png)

The Malaysian league is rated 1.5 stars and has a reputation score of 55. As shown below, I tried to normalised the reputation score to a value between 0 and 1, so that I can use it in an equation that scales the defender's duels win rate before comparing them.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2VKq.png)

Can someone advise me **what is the formula or equation I can use that takes into account the reputation score to scale the respective defensive duels win rate of both defenders into a value between 0-100% so I can compare them in a fair manner?**

I have come across some methods like min/max normalisation or z-score normalisation but both don't take into account the reputation score to scale the win rate of each defender.

I also saw that I could take the win rate and just multiply by the reputation score. (e.g. 75% * 0.15, 65%*1.00) but I realise this method can bias the values heavily towards the defenders that play in better leagues. Meaning, the defenders who play in a better leagues will almost always have a win rate that is better than defenders who play in a poorer league.

For example, Player X win rate = 0.65*1.00 = 0.65 or 65%

Player Y win rate = 0.75*0.15 = 0.11 or 11%.

So the player X who had a lower win rate than Player Y now has a higher win rate. Player Y who had a higher win rate now has a significantly lower win rate. I'm not sure if this is really the right and fair approach to compare their values, taking into account the reputation score of their respective leagues.